# Send result back to parent activity wihout finishing child activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-activity

I am working on two apps. The first one has a button that when pressed launchs an implicit intent with some data attached. The intent is captured by an `inten-filter` registered on the main activity of the other app.

What I need is that the child activity sends back some data to the parent (which is in background) immediately without finishing and must stay in foreground.

I tried to implement this through the `startActtivityForResult()` and `OnActivityResult()` way without succes. Indeed this method works only if the child activity finish.

I'm looking for other solutions, like Services...but I am quite newbie and I need to be at least addressed to the right path.

Thanks in advance.

I give you some further details:

The first activity (parent) launch the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();           
intent.setAction("xx.xx.xxxxx");
intent.putExtra("Data1", data1);
intent.putExtra("Data2", data2);
...             
startActivityForResult(intent,MANAGE_CODE);
```

and the OnActivitityResult() method is

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{                
    switch (requestCode) {
    case MANAGE_CODE:
        switch (resultCode) {
        case 0: 
                ...
                break;
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

The child activity performs this:

```
    Intent caller = getIntent();
    if ( caller.getAction().equals("xx.xx.xxxxx") ) {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra("data", "12345");
      // Set result 
          getParent().setResult(0, intent);
}
```

I omitted implementation details...I can't see the setResult( ) call works if I don't close the child activity (for example by using the finish() method)

Comment: How will the "parent" app respond?  It's in the background and might be killed by the platform, over which you have no control.  How would it receive the result anyway?  Please explain what you are trying to achieve.  I suspect you might need to rethink your approach, or as you say, as service.

Comment: perhaps use ResultReceiver between two activites

Comment: Dear Simon, probably you are right. I can't do this beacuse the parent activity is not running. Another approach could be necessary.
Waqas, I'll investigate the ResultReceiver. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run a service and have it broadcast an intent with the extras you need and then retrieve them in the BroadcastReceiver onReceive in the parent.

Example:

```
public class serviceD extends Service{
    private Intent intent_broadcast;
static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.ServicesAndBroadcastIntent";

    public void onCreate(){
        super.OnCreate();
        intent_broadcast = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        intent_broadcast.putExtra("EXTRA_MSG","data");
        sendBroadcast(intent_broadcast);
        stopSelf();
        return startId;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. Can the following workflow be right?

1) Activity of APP A (which has a BC Receiver) launchs an intent;
2) The intent is captured by an activity of APP B that comes to foreground. APP A goes to background.
3) APP B start a service used only to broadcast an intent with some data.
4) APP A (in background) retrieve the broadcast message and updates its state and does this while APP B is still in foreground.

Can it work?

Comment: @Abde Sounds about right. Try it out. As long as App A has registered the broadcast receiver for the same action there should be no problem.

Comment: I have just read in the official android documentation that a process is considered in "foreground" if it has a Broadcast Receiver that is executing its onReceive method. Another possibility might be to implement a IPC with the two apps bound to the same service, but this requires me to study carefully. However I will try and I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want the changes to be reflected in parent activity when you make changes in child activity. for that Task Affinity may help you
Check below links: look for task affinity

1) http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
2) http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack

Answer (score -1):

Please reference following codes and compare with them...

int SECOND_ACTIVITY = 2;

A activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setClassName(A.this , B.class);

intent.setClassName(A.this , B.class);


intent.setClassName(A.this, B.class);

startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY);
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
Bundle extraBundle;
if(requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY){

Log.d("SECOND_ACTIVITY_LOG","THIS CLOSE !!");

if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
extraBundle = intent.getExtras();
String str = extraBundle.getString("key1");
Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
 }

}



B activity


intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(extraBundle);
this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);//if return RESULT_OK , then A can receive.
```